# How to add a web page directly onto domain?

Tags: html, .htaccess, directory

Sorry if this isn't the appropriate place to ask this question, as it doesn't pertain directly to code, but I haven't found any help anywhere else.

So I've created a temporary landing page for my website that's just an .html file. I've uploaded it onto the host's public_html directory. In order to access that page I need to go to example.com/test.html. However, I'd like to be able to access that page by just going to example.com.

Comment: You can do that using the following rule in your htaccess file : `DirectoryIndex test.html` this will serve the page as root directory index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding this content to  `.htaccess` file in public_html directory

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex test.html
```

replace test.html with your file name

Answer (score 0):

it's entry page, for whole entry pages, you should use naming index.html, rename your page to index.html